# Validation accuracy stuck at 0.50 when training CNN siamese network based on Keras MNIST example

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

When training Siamese Convolutional Neural Network based on [Keras MNIST example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_siamese.py) it gets stuck at 0.50 validation accuracy. Moreover, training and validation loss decrease while training accuracy hovers around 0.50 as well.

Code for creating siamese network is similar to this:

```
input_shape = x_train.shape[2:]
print('input_shape:',input_shape)
# network definition
base_network = create_base_network(input_shape)

input_a = Input(shape=input_shape)
input_b = Input(shape=input_shape)

# because we re-use the same instance `base_network`,
# the weights of the network
# will be shared across the two branches
processed_a = base_network(input_a)
processed_b = base_network(input_b)

distance = Lambda(euclidean_distance,
                  output_shape=eucl_dist_output_shape)([processed_a, processed_b])

model = Model([input_a, input_b], distance)
```

Where `create_base_network` function creates ResNet50 with additional two feedforward layers of 512 and 1024, all layers frozen except for few unfrozen ones at the end.

This issue has been discussed multiple times across multiple platforms (Stackoverflow, Github, and even Reddit) but no definitive answer/solution has been provided.

Answer (score 0):

I have been troubleshooting this for few hours now. Although this does not affect that many people since this use-case is pretty specific, the ones that are affected can try following. It worked for me.

It seems that the problem is related to some low-level behaviour of Python 3.5 beyond the scope of my understanding. Switching to Python 2.7 did the trick and network is able to reach accuracy over 70% right from the beginning. Prior to this, even after 10 epochs, accuracy was stuck at 50%.

```
Train on 36000 samples, validate on 4000 samples
Epoch 1/10
36000/36000 [==============================] - 866s 24ms/step - loss: 0.2026 - accuracy: 0.7133 - val_loss: 0.2054 - val_accuracy: 0.7173

Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 0.20544, saving model to model_checkpoint/siamese_40k_headache_20thFeb-1.hdf5
Epoch 2/10
36000/36000 [==============================] - 770s 21ms/step - loss: 0.1949 - accuracy: 0.7271 - val_loss: 0.2020 - val_accuracy: 0.7235

Epoch 00002: val_loss improved from 0.20544 to 0.20204, saving model to model_checkpoint/siamese_40k_headache_20thFeb-1.hdf5
Epoch 3/10
 7040/36000 [====>.........................] - ETA: 9:12 - loss: 0.1879 - accuracy: 0.7320
```

Furthermore, validation accuracy stuck at 0.50 when training Siamese network using transfer learning might be also related to Keras's implementation of batch-normalization layer. More can be read about it [here](http://blog.datumbox.com/the-batch-normalization-layer-of-keras-is-broken/).  Manually installing this version of Keras fixes it:

```
!pip install -U --force-reinstall --no-dependencies git+https://github.com/datumbox/keras@fork/keras2.2.4
```

In no way this is a direct solution to the problem, rather a workaround that works.

Comment: I ran the same example in google colab . accuracy on training set 99.58 % . I am using python3 as runtime.

Comment: @TanmayPatil That sounds interesting. Could you share the colab notebook?